# Android Unit Test giving not mocked message for a Mockito stubbed method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I've created the following test method where I mock Settings.Secure and stub the getString method of that class.

```
@Test
public void testIsDevicePostOwner() throws Exception {
    String mockDeviceId = "2c3977ad-0867-49d6-aad8-c2762f373551";

    Post mockedPost = mock(Post.class);

    Settings.Secure mockedSecure = mock(Settings.Secure.class);

    ContentResolver mockContentResolver = mock(ContentResolver.class);

    when(mockedSecure.getString(mockContentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)).thenReturn(mockDeviceId);
}
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getString in android.provider.Settings$Secure not mocked.
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings.Secure.getString` is a static method, so `mock(Settings.Secure.class)` won't mock it. Even subclassing Settings.Secure and creating your own static getString won't help here.

I'm not sure if there's any reflection magic that can help you out in this case; none comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mock an static method, use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock)

You'll need to run with PowerMockRunner and Prepare the class for test:

```
@PrepareForTest({Settings.Secure.class})
```

For mocking the object you need to:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Settings.Secure.class);
```

Then you could try:

```
when(Settings.Secure.getString(mockContentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)).thenReturn(mockDeviceId);
```

Finally, you could test:

```
verifyStatic();
```

Comment: When mocking `Settings.Secure.class`, I found that the `Settings` class also needs to be "prepared": `@PrepareForTest({Settings.class, Settings.Secure.class})`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

in your `build.gradle`

More info here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of this setting, but surely if you are mocking framework methods this exception shouldn't be thrown and this setting should be unnecessary?  This is what the docs suggest.

Comment: When I add that setting I receive the following error so I suspect that is related:  
  
  
`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock.`